# Newbie question: New to the board, is it OK to post Jing video screencaps?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to blender, and I will surely have many questions in the weeks to come.  This is a visual platform, so I like to use screencap video to show my points.  Is it OK to post links to SWF videos from something like Jing?

Comment: I think this question belong in [meta]

Comment: Yes probably a question for meta, not for BSE. Any additional helpful information that aids in clarifying your question is always welcome but be sure to keep it relevant and straight to the point. Describing the problem or embedding an image is always preferable to remotely hosted links or videos. Also don't link to stuff that requires installing software (flash player) or logging in or registering. If possible embedding a short animated GIF is preferred

Comment: Related - http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/608/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-is-hard-to-describe and http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers and http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/817/how-to-record-steps-in-blender

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only moving images supported as part of the post are Gif, and have to be under 2mb. No other video format is supported (thankfully!).

For other formats, or longer videos, you can add links to other hosts as part of the text in your post.

Few things to keep in mind:

Your question in BSE should have a clear explanation of the issue you want to resolve **as text** and should be understandable besides the video. Don't just post: "watch this video and tell me how to fix it".

Think of video as additional support to clarify the issue.

Please keep all videos short and to the point. Don't expect people to watch for a long time while you ramble on. **Concise and clear questions get better answers**.

Also please take some time and read the help section to familiarize yourself with the site and understand the rules: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: I think they have to be under 2 MiB in order to upload them from a post, but you can embed them if you upload to imgur directly